# Is the Avantgarde Font free for commercial use?

Tags: fonts

I've been searching for a similar Century Gothic font that I can use for commercial purposes (for a site). I downloaded Avantgarde from azfonts.net but couldn't see anything regarding the license so I'm assuming it's free.

Where can I find info about the license?  If it's not free could you recommend a freeware font that's very similar to century gothic?

Comment: If there is no explicit license free, then it's subject to copyright. But it probably depends on your residence country.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a see to [this download page](http://www.azfonts.net/load_font/1196689117_avangiwo.html), you should may see : `(c) Copyright 1998 E+F Designstudio.` So this font isn't free.

But there are many AvantGarde fonts on asfont.net and some seems to have no copyright.

[CenturyGothic](http://www.azfonts.net/load_font/century_gothic.html) doesn't seem to have either.